# Call function in callback of Superagent - React

Tags: reactjs, callback, request, superagent

I want to call a function at the end of request (when I get the response) with Superagent.

```
request.post('/TextUpload')
.send({title:this.state.title1})
.end( function(res){
   console.log(res);
   this.myFunction();
})
```

But I get the error : this is null or undefined.

MyFunction() is declared and binded in the constructor.
I cannot write the code of the function directly in the callback because I do `this.props.refresh(true);` (it sends Data to the parent)

Comment: Could you please add constructor as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the error : this is null or undefined.?

This should work.Use **arrow function** to get the **lexical scope binding**

```
.end((res)=>{
   console.log(res);
   this.myFunction();
})
```

Comment: Yes I needed to wait 10 minutes before accepting the answer !